# Adding a percentage of missing values column into a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, format, multiple-columns, nan

I would like to create a piece of code in R that calculates the percentage of the missing values in each column in the data data frame.  The `NA_values` data frame creates a data frame out of the data data frame by summing up all the `NaN` rows for each column. After the calculation, I would like to add the percentage of missing columns within the `NA_values` data frame next to the missing values column `NA_value`. How I would be able to code such a thing?

```
data <- data.frame(
   salary = c(623.3,NaN , NaN, NaN ,NaN,NaN),
   emp_name = c(515.2,NaN , NaN, 2 ,3,1),
   emp_id = c (1:6), 
   new_s = c(843.25,4,5,12,4,554.4)
)

NA_values= data.frame(NA_value=colSums(is.na(data)))
```

Comment: `colMeans(is.na(data))`

Comment: Or `NA_values$NA_proportion = NA_values$NA_value / nrow(data)`